# Trying to get price was from newegg.com, keep getting an index error

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, index-error

Im trying to get a the price-was container from newegg.com for graphics cards that are on sale, right now iv got the text extracted but it comes out with a lot of spaces new lines and repeated numbers.

```
price2 = container.findAll('li', {'class', 'price-was'})
price3 = price2[0].text.split()
price_was = price3[0]
```

i used the split() function to clean everything up and it got me something like this ['$489.99', '489.99'].
but for some reason i get an index error list index out of range when i call price3[0]. iv tried everything i could think of and find but i dont understand why its not working, doesnt split() turn a string into an array. if anyone can help me better understand whats going on thats much appreciated. thank you :>

EDIT

```
[<li class="price-was">
       $479.99
            <span class="price-was-data" style="display: none">479.99</span>
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and post the output of `print(price2)`?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem, based on the html you posted.

Comment: Yeah i dont know why its not working, in theory it should work fine. do you have any idea what might not make it work? should i post all my code?

Comment: Yes, post the code with the url; it might help.

Comment: HOLY CRAP, i looked over just a simple thing. the code was fine, just the way i had it set up meant that it was trying to index blank lists from cards that arnt on sale and only list the ones that are. a simple if statement  fixed my problem. i feel really dumb. thank you so much for all your help.